# focus on the user control in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

I have a user control(error control) in a master page. by default the user control is hidden(visible false)

on click of a submit button  i am showing the error control.Now on post back I want to bring focus to this control.I am writing the java script in register Startup script as following:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "Scroll", "window.scrollTo(0, 0)", true);
```

on postback page goes up shows this control and then comes back to its previous scroll position.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set [`MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maintainscrollpositiononpostback.aspx) to `true` in the [page directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a.aspx) at the top of your page/master page or in the [`<pages>` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/950xf363.aspx) of your web.config?

You could also look at using the [`Focus` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.focus.aspx) of the control in your postback handler

**Edit to clarify:**

If any of these are set to `true` then it's very likely that they will override your startup script to send the page back to the top of the page - have you tried setting it to false in either the Page directive, or on the Page object in the same code that displays the error control?

Comment: Hi I am calling followin method on button click event still no use.. as u can see I have tried script manager.setfocus also but no respite.
public void SetFocus()
        {
            Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = false;
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "Scroll", "window.scrollTo(0, 0)", true);
           // ScriptManager1.SetFocus(ErrorControl1.FocusControl);
        }

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have solved this issue. following is the way i am doing it...

i have added a text box of width Zero% in the same  where my user control(error control is placed)

now whenever an error occurs I call following method.

```
public void SetFocus()
        {
            ScriptManager3.SetFocus(txtFocus.ClientID);
        }
```

although error control is not focused in reality this clever work around helps me achieve my goal.

hope it is helpful  for others

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void Control_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Control GotFocus : " + ((sender as Control).Name));
    }
```